# Creating proper GeoJSON from PostGIS data using node.js

Tags: postgis, leaflet, geojson, node-js

I am trying to build a GeoJSON object from a SQL query to some GIS point data in a postgis postgresql database. A snippet of my node.js app.js is below.

As it stands I understand building the type and features, but don't know how to attach a properties properties to each GeoJSON record (in the below, it all renders at the end, separate from (not collated with) the features).

THE QUESTION: What do I need to do so that the properties attach (collate) for each record in the loop that builds the GeoJSON So that it looks more like this http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#examples?

```
function GrabData(bounds, res){

  pg.connect(conn, function(err, client){

  var moisql = 'SELECT ttl, (ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom)) as locale from cpag;'


  client.query(moisql, function(err, result){
    var featureCollection = new FeatureCollection();

    for(i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++){
      featureCollection.features[i] = JSON.parse(result.rows[i].locale);
      featureCollection.properties[i] = JSON.parse(result.rows[i].ttl); //this is wrong
   }

   res.send(featureCollection);
   });

});
}

 function FeatureCollection(){
   this.type = 'FeatureCollection';
   this.features = new Array();
   this.properties = new Object;  //this is wrong
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [function](https://github.com/codeforamerica/nodetiles-core/blob/master/datasources/PostGIS.js#L94) should work for you; just pass the `result.rows` object as the argument;

```
  toGeoJson: function(rows){
    var obj, i;

    obj = {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: []
    };

    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var item, feature, geometry;
      item = rows[i];

      geometry = JSON.parse(item.geometry);
      delete item.geometry;

      feature = {
        type: "Feature",
        properties: item,
        geometry: geometry
      }

      obj.features.push(feature);
    } 
    return obj;
  }
```